# sql server convert datetime to varchar with hyphens as separators

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to convert this SQL Server 2008 R2 `datetime` value:

```
06/30/2013 09:25:35.000
```

to

```
06_30_2013_09_25_35_000
```

Haven't been able to find a solution on the net for this. Basically I want to return a string for use in a script.

I can get the date part with this but not sure how to get the format I need?

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(30), my_date_time, 103) AS Expr1
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The script is probably better at this than sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replace after combining two of the date formats together:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(
        CONVERT(nvarchar(30), getdate(), 110) + ' ' +
        CONVERT(nvarchar(30), getdate(), 14),
        '-', '_'),
        ' ', '_'),
        ':', '_'),
        '.', '_')
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16496

Answer (score 0):

Super ugly, but you can do this with nesting the `replace` function:

```
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(convert(nvarchar(30), my_date_time, 103) ,'/','_')
, ' ', '_')
, ':', '_')
, '.', '_')
```